Checkbox no funciona y deja enviar el formulario
Tengo esta gran duda con mi script. Ando haciendo pruebas con un checkbox para aviso de privacidad, la cuestión es que sin estar encasillado el formulario se envía y no debería pasar. ¿Alguien tiene una solución a esto?


function validation() {
  var checkbox = document.getElementById("avisoPrivacidad");
  if (!checkbox.checked) {
    document.getElementById("errorPrivacidad").innerHTML = "Por favor, acepta el Aviso de Privacidad.";
    return false;
  }
  document.getElementById("successPrivacidad").innerHTML = "¡Gracias!";
  return true;
}
<form action="<?= base_url() ?>contratarPlanes" id="signup" class="form" method="post">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 mb-3 text-center custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="avisoPrivacidad" value="aceptado" id="avisoPrivacidad"> <label for="avisoPrivacidad" class="avisoPrivacidad">*Aceptar Aviso de Privacidad</label> <a href="<?= base_url() ?>avisoDePrivacidad" class="text-dark" rel="noopener noreferrer"
      target="_blank">(Ver)</a><br>
    <p id="errorPrivacidad"></p>
    <p id="successPrivacidad"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 form-group text-center">
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" name="submitForm" onClick="validation()" class="btn-contratar">
  </div>
</form>




Está mal implementado. Desactiva el botón Enviar, y activalo sólo si el checkbox ha sido marcado. Así evitas una acción que posteriormente podría ser desestimada.

El siguiente script (usando javascript) previene el envío de tu formulario a menos que se marque el checkbox:
<script>
  const avisoPrivacidadCheckbox = document.querySelector(
    'input[name="avisoPrivacidad"]
  ');
  const submitFormButton = document.querySelector(
    'input[name="submitForm"]'
  );

  submitFormButton.addEventListener(
    'click',
    function(event) {
      if (!avisoPrivacidadCheckbox.checked) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('Debe aceptar el aviso de privacidad para enviar el formulario.');
      }
    }
  );
</script>

No es necesario usar onClick="validation()" en el botón pues ya se le agrega un eventListener que detecta cuando se hace click sobre él.
